# Trouble installing freeglut package

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, dependencies, opengl

Here are the outputs from running the respective commands:

- `sudo apt-get update results`

  http://paste.ubuntu.com/15291163/
- `sudo apt-get install build-essential results`

  http://paste.ubuntu.com/15291437/
- `$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev` results:

  ```
  peace@peace:~$ sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  E: Unable to locate package freeglut3-dev
  ```

Comment: try using `-f` with your command

Comment: You need to fix your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file so that the update can complete successfully - also it's `build-essential` not `build essential`

Comment: @Mostafa Where should I use -f?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver .. But It isn't working yet.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: This is the output -- http://paste.ubuntu.com/15291455/ .Everything else remains same.

Comment: This is my sources.list http://paste.ubuntu.com/15291507/

Answer (score 0):

There was dependency issue due to which package "freeglut3-dev" was not being installed.I downgraded the package version by running

```
$ sudo aptitude install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev
```

Rest of things were done by terminal itself.